# Android Hello World Qt 5.2

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt5, qmake

I can't get the hello world project to compile when I try it on an AVD. Below is the error I get when I try to compile it.

```
14:57:28: Running steps for project AnotherTest...
14:57:28: Starting: "C:\Qt\5.2.1\android_armv5\bin\qmake.exe" "C:\Users\Darrel\Desktop\New folder\AnotherTest\AnotherTest.pro" -r -spec android-g++ "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=declarative_debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug"
The system cannot find the path specified.
14:57:28: The process "C:\Qt\5.2.1\android_armv5\bin\qmake.exe" exited normally.
14:57:28: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 
C:\Users\Darrel\android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -c -Wno-psabi -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-short-enums -DANDROID -Wa,--noexecstack -std=gnu++0x -g -g -gdwarf-2 -marm -O0 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -Wall -Wno-psabi -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_OS_ANDROID_GCC_48_WORKAROUND -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\..\..\..\..\Qt\5.2.1\android_armv5\mkspecs\android-g++ -I..\AnotherTest -I..\..\..\..\..\Qt\5.2.1\android_armv5\include -I..\..\..\..\..\Qt\5.2.1\android_armv5\include\QtQuick -I..\..\..\..\..\Qt\5.2.1\android_armv5\include\QtQml -I..\..\..\..\..\Qt\5.2.1\android_armv5\include\QtWidgets -I..\..\..\..\..\Qt\5.2.1\android_armv5\include\QtNetwork -I..\..\..\..\..\Qt\5.2.1\android_armv5\include\QtGui -I..\..\..\..\..\Qt\5.2.1\android_armv5\include\QtCore -I. -I..\..\..\android-ndk-r9d\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\include -I..\..\..\android-ndk-r9d\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\libs\armeabi\include -I..\..\..\android-ndk-r9d\platforms\android-9\arch-arm\usr\include -I. -o main.obj ..\AnotherTest\main.cpp
C:\Qt\5.2.1\android_armv5\bin\rcc.exe -name qml ..\AnotherTest\qml.qrc -o qrc_qml.cpp
C:\Users\Darrel\android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -c -Wno-psabi -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-short-enums -DANDROID -Wa,--noexecstack -std=gnu++0x -g -g -gdwarf-2 -marm -O0 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -Wall -Wno-psabi -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_OS_ANDROID_GCC_48_WORKAROUND -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\..\..\..\..\Qt\5.2.1\android_armv5\mkspecs\android-g++ -I..\AnotherTest -I..\..\..\..\..\Qt\5.2.1\android_armv5\include -I..\..\..\..\..\Qt\5.2.1\android_armv5\include\QtQuick -I..\..\..\..\..\Qt\5.2.1\android_armv5\include\QtQml -I..\..\..\..\..\Qt\5.2.1\android_armv5\include\QtWidgets -I..\..\..\..\..\Qt\5.2.1\android_armv5\include\QtNetwork -I..\..\..\..\..\Qt\5.2.1\android_armv5\include\QtGui -I..\..\..\..\..\Qt\5.2.1\android_armv5\include\QtCore -I. -I..\..\..\android-ndk-r9d\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\include -I..\..\..\android-ndk-r9d\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\libs\armeabi\include -I..\..\..\android-ndk-r9d\platforms\android-9\arch-arm\usr\include -I. -o qrc_qml.obj qrc_qml.cpp
C:\Users\Darrel\android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ --sysroot=C:\Users\Darrel\android-ndk-r9d/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/ -Wl,-soname,libAnotherTest.so -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared -o libAnotherTest.so main.obj qrc_qml.obj   -LC:\Users\Darrel\android-ndk-r9d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi -LC:\Users\Darrel\android-ndk-r9d/platforms/android-9/arch-arm//usr/lib -LC:\Qt\5.2.1\android_armv5\lib -lQt5Quick -Lc:\Utils\android\ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi -Lc:\Utils\android\ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-arm//usr/lib -LC:\Utils\icu32_51_1_mingw48\lib -LC:\utils\postgresql\pgsql\lib -LC:\utils\mysql\mysql\lib -LC:\Utils\pgsql\lib -LC:\temp\opensll-android-master\openssl-android-master\lib -LC:\Qt\5.2.1\android_armv5/lib -lQt5Qml -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Network -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGLESv2 -lgnustl_shared -llog -lz -lm -ldl -lc -lgcc
14:57:31: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited normally.
14:57:31: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" INSTALL_ROOT="C:\Users\Darrel\Desktop\New folder\build-AnotherTest-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_8_Qt_5_2_1-Debug\android-build" install
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
makefile:867: recipe for target 'install_target' failed
mingw32-make: *** [install_target] Error 1
14:57:32: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project AnotherTest (kit: Android for armeabi (GCC 4.8, Qt 5.2.1))
When executing step 'Copy application data'
14:57:32: Elapsed time: 00:04.
```

Comment: have you checked your path you giving that contains `New folder` try to replace it with `New_folder` changing the folder name

Comment: Nice Catch! The posted problem is fixed! Thank you! Although now I have a whole slew of new problems :/

Comment: update your answer again and let me see what causes these new problems

Comment: How do I update an answer?

Comment: @Overtim3: question, not answer, but please do not update it into a different issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is mentioned in the comment, your path is not correct because it contains a space which is apparently not handled properly by qmake:

```
C:\Users\Darrel\Desktop\New folder\AnotherTest\AnotherTest.pro
                           ^
```

Try to remove that, so something like this should work:

```
C:\Users\Darrel\Desktop\Newfolder\AnotherTest\AnotherTest.pro

                        ^^^^^^^^
```